# WebP is pixelated

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, webp

I'm struggling with a problem with pixelated images. I downloaded the logo of Amazon(PNG) then I moved it to my Android project files and converted it to WebP. The problem is that image it's pixelated.

```
Image(
    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.amazon),
    contentDescription = "",
    modifier = Modifier
        .align(Alignment.Center)
        .matchParentSize()
        .scale(3F, 3F),
    contentScale = ContentScale.Fit
)
```

[image]

I tried downloading images in SVG format and convert to XML but it doesn't work at all.
What should I do to display a clear image?

Comment: Both PNG and WebP, are not vector formats, so the image can't be scaled correctly. SVG converted to XML is the right approach. Show how you tried to use it, as well as the XML file you use.

Comment: `scale(3F, 3F),` Change to scale(1F, 1F), You did not tell that you tried to enlarge resolution.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov drawable -> new -> Vector Asset then I selected my SVG and converted to xml. Output:

<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="50dp"
    android:height="16dp"
    android:viewportWidth="50"
    android:viewportHeight="16">
  <path
      android:pathData="M0,0h50v15.0625h-50z"/>
</vector>
Android Studio can't render that image and when I'm running the app Image() is blank

Comment: @blackapps On  scale(1F, 1F) looks fine but I need to enlarge that image. How Can I do that?

Comment: @Wafi_ck this path doesn't looks like it contain any significant image. Where your SVG came from?

Comment: @PhilipDukhov I know that. It comes from Figma project. I can share wiht you that image in SVG format https://ufile.io/19ronoau As you can see it display fine in browser

Comment: Your SVG is not a vector image, it contains PNG data inside: you can open it with text editor and see `xlink:href="data:image/png;base64`. That's why it cannot be converted into XML. Ask your designer to prepare a vector image instead.

Comment: Ahh ok. Thanks!